# Hiding a field based on another field's hidden property

Tags: rdlc

I'm trying to create a RDLC report. My data look like this:

```
Room      Time    Capacity   Attendee
 101      8:00am     100        Fred
 101      8:00am     100        Bob
 101      8:00am     100        Jim
 101      1:00pm     100        Tom
 101      1:00pm     100        Steve
 101      1:00pm     100        Mike
 etc.
```

I'd like my report to look like this:

```
Room      Time    Capacity   Attendee
 101      8:00am     100        Fred
                                Bob
                                Jim
          1:00pm     100        Tom
                                Steve
                                Mike
```

I've turned on Hide Duplicates for the **Room** and **Time** columns and that works great:

```
 Room      Time    Capacity   Attendee
 101      8:00am     100        Fred
                     100        Bob
                     100        Jim
          1:00pm     100        Tom
                     100        Steve
                     100        Mike
```

But I don't know how to handle the capacity column. I can't set Hide Duplicates on it, because the  AM and PM capacities are the same and it will hide the PM capacity.

I thought maybe I could use the **Time** text box's hidden property, but there doesn't seem to be a way to access it from another text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. On the Capacity field, I set HideDuplicates to the field I was grouping the Time on. So it only suppressed duplicates in that group. Which is what I wanted.